# Decimal.TryParse - missing separator?

Tags: c#, .net, decimal, tryparse, valueconverter

I have strange situation, when I use API. I get object in JSON, which I deserialize. This object contains string property which is parsed to decimal.

To do this I use this code. I live in Poland where decimal separator is ',', so I use replace method.

```
string input ="160.00"; //value from API

decimal result;
decimal.TryParse(input.Replace('.',','), out result);
```

From time to time I result is equals 16000!! (I suppose TryParse method delete separator, it not determined).
How can I prevent this situation? Can I parse

Comment: Instead of swapping the decimal separator, why not specify a culture for the call to `TryParse`?

Comment: Could you write some example code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Numbers should be serialized as `InvariantCulture` anyway so the `InvariantCulture` for parsing is a good start. The code serializing the numbers should also be checked whether it follows this *rule*.

```
string input ="160.00";
decimal result = decimal.Parse(
    input, 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Not serializing numbers as culture invariant is one of the most common source of problems like *it runs on my machine I have no idea why it doesn't on yours... oh you say your system is in a different language* oops ;-)

Comment: Even a big company that creates very sophisticated 3d cad software had this bug in their library. In our company where I use an english system everything was fine however the client had a german system and had to switch the languguage because there was no other way to run some functions because they generated invalid cad-files and it wasn't for them possible to fix it (no support).

Comment: If the API returns different values depending on culture, this will not work correctly. If the API returns 160,00 your code will return 16000 for result. But if the value is always with ., probably your solution is better.

Comment: Yes, this is true. That's why I wrote to check the serialization too to make sure the numbers are always in the _correct_ format.

Comment: Sorry I'm too tired and don't read it properly, you are right!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of replacing decimal point character you should be using a proper overload of `TryParse` method, i.e. [`decimal.TryParse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider, Decimal)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string input ="160.00";
NumberStyles style = NumberStyles.Number;
decimal number = 0;

CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
decimal.TryParse(input, style, culture, out number)
```

Make sure to specify the correct culture which is suitable for your case.